# jQuery find() does not work when given a variable

Tags: jquery

In my script, I do:

```
var target = $('#myForm input[name=target]').val(); // yields `itemControl`
```

This works:

```
$('.process').closest('.post').find('.itemControl').empty().html('Success'); 
console.log(target); // itemControl
```

But this wont (notice, I've use the var `target` itself here):

```
$('.process').closest('.post').find(target).empty().html('Success');
console.log(target); // itemControl
```

Why wont it, and how do I get this right when using a variable?

Comment: `target` is a string. It must looks like jquery selector

Comment: Because the output of the variable will be missing the "." for the class?

Comment: `.find('.' + target)`

Comment: You'd have better to set as input value `.itemControl` (a selector) not just `itemControl` (part of a selector). In this case, you could handle any selector type, not just class selector

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the selector in your `find()`-function :

```
$('.process').closest('.post').find(target).empty().html('Success');
```

It has to be **`find('.' + target)`**

Your variable only contains a string of `itemControl` and not the corresponding Object.

To use the variable as an Object inside your function you can do:

```
var target_object = $('.' + target);
```

and then `.find(target_object)`

but this would be the as I mentioned above, only with more code.

Answer (score 0):

The "find" method argument is a string. In your case you want it to be ".itemControl". Your target variable has value "itemControl" hence it doesn't give the result you expect. Instead use:

```
$('.process').closest('.post').find("."+target).empty().html('Success');
```

And it should work as you expect.